# Making and Applying Linux Security Patches

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel, patch, cve

Apologies in advance if this is off topic or posted in the wrong place

Just started hosting my own media server (CentOS Stream 8) and I'm trying to learn how to secure it. How would you apply changes from git to your kernel? in this case it would be for CVE-2021-22555.

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-35039#range-6800543

Are fixes like this automatically included in updates, or do I have to manually patch it? If so, how would you go about patching it?

Comment: You would have to compile your own kernel instead of using the one from CentOS. Fixes like these are usually included in updates. This particular one is unlikely to affect you, anyway. It just says if you try to stop yourself from being able to load un-signed drivers, if you do it wrong, it won't work. 1) why would you do that and 2) why would you care?

Comment: Usually, vulnerabilities are fixed in the major distros' packages before they are announced publically, so it would just be a case of updating your system and rebooting.

Comment: This CVE-2021-22555 does not seem to have been fixed in RHEL / Centos yet though.